# Request failed due to timeout issue on comtradeapicall

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining

Here's the issue: I have code for a Comtrade call. I'm iterating for each month in the year and splitting 5 HS Codes for each API call. Here are the details of my Python code:

```py
import comtradeapicall
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

# koneksi ke database MySQL
db_config = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "datacomtrade"
}

# menyimpan data ke database MySQL
def save_to_database_and_clean(data):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    table_name = "trade_data"
    
    # jumlah records data
    num_records = len(data)
    
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        # Mengganti nilai NaN dengan 0
        row.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        
        # Menghapus karakter "'"
        row['reporterDesc'] = row['reporterDesc'].str.replace("'", "")
        row['partnerDesc'] = row['partnerDesc'].str.replace("'", "")
        row['partner2Desc'] = row['partner2Desc'].str.replace("'", "")
        
        # Anda dapat menyesuaikan bagian ini sesuai dengan struktur tabel Anda
        insert_query = f"""
            INSERT INTO {table_name} (typeCode, freqCode, refPeriodId, refYear, refMonth, period, 
                reporterCode, reporterISO, reporterDesc, flowCode, flowDesc, partnerCode, partnerISO, 
                partnerDesc, partner2Code, partner2ISO, partner2Desc, classificationCode, classificationSearchCode, 
                isOriginalClassification, cmdCode, cmdDesc, aggrLevel, isLeaf, customsCode, customsDesc, mosCode, 
                motCode, motDesc, qtyUnitCode, qtyUnitAbbr, qty, isQtyEstimated, altQtyUnitCode, altQtyUnitAbbr, 
                altQty, isAltQtyEstimated, netWgt, isNetWgtEstimated, grossWgt, isGrossWgtEstimated, cifvalue, 
                fobvalue, primaryValue, legacyEstimationFlag, isReported, isAggregate)  
            VALUES (
                '{row['typeCode']}', '{row['freqCode']}', {row['refPeriodId']}, {row['refYear']}, {row['refMonth']}, 
                '{row['period']}', '{row['reporterCode']}', '{row['reporterISO']}', '{row['reporterDesc']}', 
                '{row['flowCode']}', '{row['flowDesc']}', '{row['partnerCode']}', '{row['partnerISO']}', 
                '{row['partnerDesc']}', '{row['partner2Code']}', '{row['partner2ISO']}', '{row['partner2Desc']}', 
                '{row['classificationCode']}', '{row['classificationSearchCode']}', {row['isOriginalClassification']}, 
                '{row['cmdCode']}', '{row['cmdDesc']}', {row['aggrLevel']}, {row['isLeaf']}, '{row['customsCode']}', 
                '{row['customsDesc']}', '{row['mosCode']}', '{row['motCode']}', '{row['motDesc']}', 
                '{row['qtyUnitCode']}', '{row['qtyUnitAbbr']}', {row['qty']}, {row['isQtyEstimated']}, 
                '{row['altQtyUnitCode']}', '{row['altQtyUnitAbbr']}', {row['altQty']}, {row['isAltQtyEstimated']}, 
                {row['netWgt']}, {row['isNetWgtEstimated']}, {row['grossWgt']}, {row['isGrossWgtEstimated']}, 
                {row['cifvalue']}, {row['fobvalue']}, {row['primaryValue']}, {row['legacyEstimationFlag']}, 
                {row['isReported']}, {row['isAggregate']}
            ); 
        """
        cursor.execute(insert_query)
    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    
    print(f"Berhasil menyimpan {num_records} records data ke database")

subscription_key = 'subcription key'

# Definisikan parameter tetap
type_code = 'C'
freq_code = 'M'
cl_code = 'HS'
flow_code = None
format_output = 'JSON'
aggregate_by = None
breakdown_mode = 'plus'
count_only = None
include_desc = True
max_records ='100000'

# Daftar tahun 
years = range(2022, 2023) 

# File Kode HS
file_path = r'F:\07 Analisa Pasar\Data\database\hscode6.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=None, usecols=[1, 2], skiprows=1)  # Kolom 2 dan 3
filtered_df = df[df[1] == 'HS22']

hs_codes = [str(code).zfill(6) for code in filtered_df[2].astype(int).astype(str)]

grouped_hs_codes = [hs_codes[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(hs_codes), 5)]

# Call API
def call_api(type_code, freq_code, cl_code, year, group):
    months = [f'{year}{month:02d}' for month in range(1, 13)]
    period_string = ','.join(months)
    
    cmd_code = ','.join(group)
    
    result = comtradeapicall.getFinalData(
        subscription_key,
        typeCode=type_code,
        freqCode=freq_code,
        clCode=cl_code,
        period=period_string,
        reporterCode=None,
        cmdCode=cmd_code,
        flowCode=flow_code,
        partnerCode=None,
        partner2Code=None,
        customsCode=None,
        motCode=None,
        maxRecords=max_records,
        format_output=format_output,
        aggregateBy=aggregate_by,
        breakdownMode=breakdown_mode,
        countOnly=count_only,
        includeDesc=include_desc
    )
    
    return result

# API Call
def perform_api_call(type_code, freq_code, cl_code, year, group, api_call_number):
    print(f"API Call #{api_call_number}: Mengerjakan API Call untuk tahun {year} dan kelompok HS: {group}")
    api_result = call_api(type_code, freq_code, cl_code, year, group)
    # Filter world
    api_result = api_result[api_result['partnerCode'] != 0]
    save_to_database_and_clean(api_result)
    print(f"API Call #{api_call_number}: Berhasil mendapatkan {len(api_result)} data untuk tahun {year} dan kelompok HS: {group}. Melanjutkan ke API Call berikutnya")
    
# Mulai eksekusi API Call
api_call_number = 0  
for year in years:
    for group in grouped_hs_codes:
        api_call_number += 1  # penomoran
        perform_api_call(type_code, freq_code, cl_code, year, group, api_call_number)
```

However, every time I run the code, I always get the error:

> "Request failed due to timeout"

I really need this code for my work. Any suggestions?

I hope to obtain the desired data without encountering the error:

> "Request failed due to timeout"

Comment: maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: better show full error message (starting at word `Traceback`) - it may have other useful information.